# Local module descriptor class for not found

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started working with flutter and now I am working on this app. Every time the app is launched I get a lot of errors and have no idea how to fix them. The errors first occurred when I tried to authenticate users and now I don't know how to get rid of them. What's more, my isLogin bool is not being changed when pressing a button. I enclose a snippet of my code and a report of debug console errors. Thanks in advance.

```
  class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    bool isLogin = true;
    final _passwordNode = FocusNode();
    final _conPasswordNode = FocusNode();
    print(isLogin);
    
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _passwordNode.dispose();
      _conPasswordNode.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    void _authUser(String email, String password) {
      if (isLogin == false) {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      }
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      dispose();
    }

    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: \[
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    label: Text('Email adress'),
                  ),
                  onSaved: (newValue) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordNode);
                    print('it works');
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  focusNode: _passwordNode,
                  obscureText: true,
                  onSaved: (newValue) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_conPasswordNode);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    label: Text('Password'),
                  ),
                ),
                if (isLogin == false)
                  TextFormField(
                    focusNode: _conPasswordNode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      label: Text('Confirm password'),
                    ),
                  ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isLogin = !isLogin;
                    });
                    print('$isLogin button');
                  },
                  child: Text(isLogin == true ? 'SignUp' : 'Login'),
                ),
              \],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

    W/DynamiteModule(11034): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/TetheringManager(11034): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.recipea_app
D/ConnectivityManager(11034): ConnectivityManager() mContext=androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication@b2a8ae5 getOpPackageName()=com.example.recipea_app getBasePackageName()=com.example.recipea_app getPackageName()=com.example.recipea_app
I/DynamiteModule(11034): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11034): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2
I/ple.recipea_ap(11034): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(11034): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 294 native methods...
W/ple.recipea_ap(11034): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(11034): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
```